# Why can't I run AssaultCube built from source?

Tags: c++, open-source

a error with open source.

I have been playing AssaultCube for about 2 weeks and I found that it is open source. I downloaded from SourceForge and I got everything to compile but... It could not find 3 .DLL(libvorbisfile.dll, libogg.dll, libvorbis.dll) files so I downloaded them and put them in `\windows\`. Now i get the error "the procedure entry point vorvis_synthesis_halfrate could not be located in the dynamic link library libvorbis.dll"

How do i fix this error? Btw im using windows 7 and VC++ 2008.

PS. I have googled and posted other places and no one knows :(

Comment: Do you have the correct versions? Why not copy the ones from the game directory you had working?

Comment: you're supposed to select the answer that best helped you. That helps people with the same problem in the future. There's a checkmark option with each answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to get the spelling right, and I don't know who made the mistake here.

The actual function name is `vorbis_synthesis_halfrate` not `vorvis_synthesis_halfrate`. (B not V). Googling that turns up quite a few results. It's indeed a "recent" function, and older Vorbis versions don't have it. GMan's answer (which he hid in a comment) is probably the easiest: the AssaultCube installer will install new versions. The harder alternative is to download the relevant sources from http://xiph.org/vorbis/ and build those DLLs yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mismatch between the stub .libs you linked against at compile time and the dynamic libraries you actually have in the PATH.

Comment: @blood: Get the correct versions.

Comment: of the .dll's? i just found them on the internet :O how do i know if i have the right ones?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the [Vorbis site](http://xiph.org/downloads/) has the DLLs available for download.  On their Downloads page there is vorbis-tools 1.2.0 (win32 binaries) which includes the DLLs you need.  I'm running Win7 and they work great.